# Octave contourf() Not Coloring in the Line

Tags: octave, contourf

I'm having trouble filling in my curves using contourf() on Octave. I'm running Octave 3.6.4 on Mac OS X 10.8.5.

When I use contour(x,fp,data3) I get the following, which is correct:
[Contour plot of data, not filled]

However, when I want try contourf(x,fp,data3) in order to fill in the gaps I get this monstrosity: 
[Contourf plot of data, filled, but not correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8rnm.png)

What can I do to fix this? I've read the contourf() documentation and can't see anything there that I'm missing. Any advice would be helpful.

Thanks!

P.S. Here's a link to a smaller version of the data file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lmvdzi7l42tasr8/Ch942.csv?dl=0. The whole file is huge, so this represents the first few lines but still shows the problem when plotted in Octave.

Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation points to post more than two links, so I've deleted the contour() plot that looks right, but isn't filled in. Sorry.

Comment: Can you add some sample data? My best guess is that there are NaNs (not quite a duplicate, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26488772/matlab-octave-havent-the-same-result-with-contourf and http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=42766 for the bug report & workaround)

Comment: There are definitely no NaNs. I saw those other posts and checked. The data that I'm plotting comes from a .csv file that I created using Excel so it was easy to verify that that's not the problem. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Can you upload your data or create some artifical data which shows the problem?

Comment: @cbw: If I use `contourf(load("Ch942.csv"))` on Octave 4.0 the generated plot looks fine. So perhaps this is a problem in 3.6.4 which is fixed. Btw, Octave 4.0 is stable and you really should consider updating. See http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X

Comment: Thanks for checking. I may have to update then.

Comment: @cbw: Any progress on this? Perhaps it's this bug: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?42580